# ListView Force Close

Tags: android

I am writing a Class that gets the File's in a folder, and displays the contents in a list view. the application force closes when i run this activity... I Debugged for a while, and searched through logcat, and I cannot find the problem...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
    if(!root.exists()){
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.folders, buildDirArray(root)));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
    }
public String[] buildDirArray(File dir){
int temp = dir.list().length;
String[] tm = dir.list();
String[] tmp = new String[temp];
for(int i=1;i==dir.list().length;i++){
    tmp[i]=tm[i];
}

    return tmp;

}
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated...
Logcat Data:

```
07-13 20:41:21.205: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-13 20:41:29.045: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-13 20:41:30.345: ERROR/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
07-13 20:41:30.345: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-13 20:41:30.345: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-13 20:41:30.364: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-13 20:41:36.015: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-13 20:41:36.015: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-13 20:41:36.295: ERROR/System(58): Failure starting core service
07-13 20:41:36.295: ERROR/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
07-13 20:41:36.295: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-13 20:41:36.295: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-13 20:41:36.295: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-13 20:41:36.295: ERROR/System(58):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
07-13 20:41:37.315: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-13 20:41:37.325: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-13 20:41:37.325: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-13 20:41:37.346: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-13 20:41:37.356: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-13 20:41:40.414: ERROR/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
07-13 20:41:42.795: ERROR/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-13 20:41:42.945: ERROR/logwrapper(148): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-13 20:41:43.065: ERROR/logwrapper(149): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-13 20:41:54.824: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282): You have to add
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282): to your AndroidManifest.xml !
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10033 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:236)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:250)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.acquireWakeLock(BaseGameActivity.java:202)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:165)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:82)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:1981)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-13 20:43:11.984: ERROR/AndEngine(282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.momentum.xpad/com.momentum.xpad.folders}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.momentum.xpad.main.onOptionsItemSelected(main.java:69)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2195)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-13 20:43:20.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the logCat result?

Comment: The LogCat output would be nice,.

Comment: Re-check LogCat again. If you read the "Log" tab you will see all logs and the crash log will appear as a stacktrace printed in read when your app FC. That information would be very helpful in order to track down your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The log says that:

```
You have to add  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> to your AndroidManifest.xml !
```

Oh some lines further down there is an other error in the log:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.momentum.xpad/com.momentum.xpad.folders}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 0):

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.momentum.xpad/com.momentum.xpad.folders}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Have you declared it in your Manifest?